# How to install sources for plug-in development in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am developing a plug-in for Eclipse.

I already worked with Eclipse variants for plug-in development. Having downloaded such an Eclipse you can for example put the text cursor on the identifier `IEditorPart` and press F3.

Then the source code of `IEditorPart` is shown.

If an exception happens the stack trace is shown in the debugger; you can click on the stack trace and the source line is shown.

My problem is that I'm using a CDT Eclipse (because most of my projects are C projects) and I have installed the plug-in development feature later on.

When I press F3 the Java byte code disassembly of `IEditorPart` is shown - and a message that the source code cannot be displayed because the Eclipse source codes are not installed.

The same is true for the stack trace which makes debugging very hard.

Question: How can I install the Eclipse source codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source code is usually in an 'SDK' install or sometimes 'xxx Developer Resources'.

For the core Eclipse the 'Eclipse Project SDK' should contain the source. Just install that from the main update site for your version of Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks. Installing the Developer Resources did the job!